# Variance of stochastic process

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-distribution

I have stochastic process like: $Z(t) = X(t) - 0,5t$ where $X(t)$ is a Poisson process with intensity = 0,5.

I need to find a variance of stochastic proces $Z(t)$ when $t=2$.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** $\operatorname{Var}(X(t) - 0.5 t) = \operatorname{Var}(X(t))$.

Comment: is $Var(X(t))$ related to $t$ in Poisson process? I have a two diffrent formula: $Var(X(t)) = \lambda$ or $Var(X(t)) = \lambda * t$? And im wondering which is correct one

Comment: Yes, it is related. As per the definition of a Poisson (counting) process, $X(t) \sim \operatorname{Pois}(\lambda t)$, so $\operatorname{Var}(X(t)) = \lambda t$.